# Exchange Environment Not Working

Tags: exchange-2003, datastore

I have just been given a client whose exchange server was not set up correctly. The server is running Windows Server 2003 and Exchange 2003 as well.

When I try to mount the store it is coming up with an error: an internal processing error has occurred. try restarting exchange system manager or the microsoft exchange information store. ID no c1041724

Can someone please tell me how I can restart with a fresh database and log files, ignoring this original store. There is no information that needs to be moved over from the old store.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want a fresh store just delete the databases and transaction log files (the contents of the MDBDATA folder) and start the information store. It will create a new, empty database. Be sure this is what you want before you do it.